# C# DirectSound Buffer.Write() Argument Exception (DirectX SDK June 2010)

Tags: c#, buffer, directsound

Has anyone here ever worked with DirectSound buffers? I'm trying to get a continuous circular buffer going by using a timer to write new data to the buffer every time a % of it has been played. I'm using an ms timer to do this.

```
    private void tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Int32 read, write;
        buffer.GetCurrentPosition(out read, out write);

        if (read > 0)
            Main.Record(buffer, (write / 2), (read / 2) - 1);
    }
```

When I use the Record() function, this is performed:

```
        short[] data;
        int size;

        if (end > start)
            size = end - start;
        else
            size = BUFFER_SIZE - end + start;

        data = new short[size];

        foreach (Voice v in voices)
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                data[i] += v.Record();
                v.incLife();
            }

         buffer.Write(start, data, LockFlag.None);
```

I am using LockFlag.None because I don't want the buffer to be locked so I can continuously write to it. However, if I use LockFlag.None, I get an ArgumentException. If I use LockFlag.EntireBuffer, I get an AccessViolationException.

Does anyone have an explanation for this or how to get around it (or suggestions on a better circular buffer implementation)?